# How can I map and save values passed by props into an array of LoggBockRowItem in my LoggBockRowList class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class LoggBockRowList extends Component{
    state ={
        loggbocks: [null],
    }

    handleloggbocks = () => {
        this.setState({loggbocks: [this.props.loggbocks.map(loggbock =>
            <LoggBockRowItem
                key={loggbock.key}
                id={loggbock.id}
                datum={loggbock.datum}
                tid={loggbock.tid}
                skift={loggbock.skift}
                anläggningsdel={loggbock.anläggningsdel}
                orsak={loggbock.orsak}
                driftstatus={loggbock.driftstatus}
                beskrivning={loggbock.beskrivning}
                plats={loggbock.plats}
                rapporterare={loggbock.rapporterare}
            />)]
        })   
    }

    render(){
      this.handleloggbocks();
      return <ul>{this.loggbocks}</ul>
    }
}
```

Im trying to save down the values given by props into an array of `<LoggBockRowItem />` in my `LoggBockRowList` class while also returning the array to be rendered

Comment: What is the purpose of saving a list of `<LoggBockRowItem />` into the state?

Comment: ultimately i have a fake database with objects and i want to be able to change the values of the objects and to do that i need to save down the objects/values somewhere in my project

Comment: But you can just save objects into the state, not components

Comment: okay could you give me and example of how you would do that in my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the whole component in the state. You can just save the objects into the state and use that to render the jsx.

Also if you want to save the props into the state you can use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` method.

```
class LoggBockRowList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggbocks: null
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
      loggbocks: props.loggbocks
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.loggbocks &&
          this.state.loggbocks.map((loggbock) => (
            <LoggBockRowItem
              key={loggbock.key}
              id={loggbock.id}
              datum={loggbock.datum}
              tid={loggbock.tid}
              skift={loggbock.skift}
              anläggningsdel={loggbock.anläggningsdel}
              orsak={loggbock.orsak}
              driftstatus={loggbock.driftstatus}
              beskrivning={loggbock.beskrivning}
              plats={loggbock.plats}
              rapporterare={loggbock.rapporterare}
            />
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: aha smart whats the point of this?`(this.state.loggbocks &&)`. isnt `(this.state.loggbocks.map())` enough for it too render the state as a  `LoggBockRowItem`?

Comment: This is just an extra check to see if loggbocks are not null before applying map on it.

Comment: @BADRUM you can replace `this.state.loggbocks &&` check with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator like this:
`this.state.loggbocks?.map(...)`